# Opening a file relative to server folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

When I try opening a file it tries to use "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\9.0" as the base directory.

How can I get the working directory of the web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~");
```

Comment: Yeah initially, I was trying to do this in the datacontext class and saw that I had no access to it. I moved this logic out of the model and into the controller.